# Array type has incomplete element type when define new data type

Tags: c, c89

I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    typedef int new_type[];
    new_type Number[8];
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler (Gcc- 4.9.2) shows error: **array type has incomplete element type**.
I have some questions:
1. Is the definition of `new_type` through typedef accepted by C90 standard? In this case, `new_type` is a data type that defines **an array** of undefined number of element or **a pointer** to an array of `int`?
2.If we keep the line `typedef int new_type[];`, how can we define a variable of type `new_type`?
  Thank you for your help.

Comment: How big should `Number` be? It has 8 elements, but the elements are arrays of indeterminate size. That can't be allocated.

Comment: Note: `typedef` at local scope is not very useful And what purpose an array-`typedef` of undetermined size would be good for is very questionable.

Comment: Why not use `typedef int my_int; my_int a[8];`? (have the `typedef` at file-scope).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the definition of new_type through typedef accepted by C90 standard? In this case, new_type is a data type that defines an array of undefined number of element or a pointer to an array of int?

The typedef itself is not a problem, since you can typedef incomplete types (`typedef struct A A_s;`). And `new_type` is indeed pretty much what you think it is.

> If we keep the line `typedef int new_type[];`, how can we define a variable of type new_type?

For a variable definition, the type of the variable must be a complete type, so:

```
typedef int new_type[];
new_type Number = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Will result in `Number` being an array of `int` of size 3. However, you try to define Number as an array of `int[]` of size 8 (`int Number[8][];`).

But an array of unspecified size cannot be used to define any variable, array or be a member of a structure<sup>1</sup> (no incomplete type can be used for those purposes).

---

<sub>1. Unless it's the last one, a *flexible array member* is allowed (with many restrictions on it).</sub>

Comment: but if I change it to `new_type Number={0};` it builds successful but how does compiler knows the actual size of 'Number' ?

Comment: @TonyJ - Because you provided an array initializer (`{0}`). It has 1 element (`0`), so the size can be deduced to be 1.